# Django datetime/timedelta incompatible type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to subtract 2 datetimes from my csv file.

Purchase Is a column in csv file.

```
orders["Closed"] = pd.to_datetime(orders["Purchase"]).dt.minute.apply(lambda x: x + 15)

 first = orders.loc[x]["Check Closed"]
 second = pd.to_timedelta(orders[(orders["ID"] == x)]["Purchase"])
 duration_time = (first - second).time()
 return duration_time
```

x - is client's ID from another csv file.

When I'm trying to run this code, I have:

```
 incompatible type for a datetime/timedelta operation [__rsub__].
```

Is it problem, that "Closed" is a timedelta, so I couldn't subtract datetime and timedelta, and how can I solve this. Thanks.

Comment: How is this related to django? Looks like pandas only.

Comment: Provide your data and expected output for around 10 rows.